# Silverstripe 4 File Upload XML

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have a requirement where the client needs to upload XML files to the CMS but I get the error "Extension is not allowed". Is there away to allow XML files? I've added xml to setAllowedExtensions on the uploadfield but this still does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So other than setting the allowed extensions on the UploadField I had to add the extension to the global config for files in my site config.

```
SilverStripe\Assets\File: 
   allowed_extensions:
      - 'xml'
```